# About the scalar multiplication on Koblitz curve in FIPS PUB 186-4 (2013)

Tags: elliptic-curves

In [FIPS PUB 186-4](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf#page=117), the computation of scalar multiplication on Koblitz curves is given in p.106~109. In p.109, step 11.3, $(r_0,r_1)$ is updated with $(r_1+\mu\,r_0/2,-r_0/2)$. But under certain case, when $r_0$ is even, $\mu=-1$, then the while loop 11 will never stop.

How can this be overcome?